# Is it possible to get aws ec2 instance id based on its IP address

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, puppet, puppetmaster, aws-cli

I have list of IP addressed, I want to find if instances associated with the IP address are still running or terminated. I am launching and terminating lot of instances on daily basis, just want to remove their certificates from puppetmaster.

If there is any alternative method, I can achieve my goal, I can do that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=ip-address,Values=IP_1,..IP_N`

Should do what you need.

use the filter name of `private-ip-address` to select using private address in your VPC.

Pipe through something like

`jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | .InstanceId, .PublicIpAddress'`

if you want the corresponding InstanceID

Comment: You don't need to use `jq`, you can pass a `--query` option to extract parts of the output: `aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=ip-address,Values=IP_1,..IP_N --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,PublicIpAddress]`See [Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html) for more details. Note that `--query` uses [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/), which is slightly different from `jq`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use --query and --output formats if you want to use this in a bash script.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values=x.x.x.x --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --output text
```

This will give you text response without json formatting

```
i-03c1ad0d6abe32323
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to use [CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/) to listen for EC2 instances being terminated, and have the listener (which could be a [Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/), or some custom service listening to SQS) remove the corresponding certificates from Puppet.

References:

- [Automating Amazon EC2 with CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/automating_with_cloudwatch_events.html)
- [New CloudWatch Events – Track and Respond to Changes to Your AWS Resources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cloudwatch-events-track-and-respond-to-changes-to-your-aws-resources/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep`

```bash
 aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values=x.x.x.x | grep 'InstanceId'
```

Note: dont use `InstanceId` keyword in Tag or Name

Answer (score 0):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values=10.xxx.xx.xx,10.yyy.yy.yy --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --output text
```

Comment: You can apply multiple instance id's or single ip as well. Redirect above command to a file to store instance id's. aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=private-ip-address,Values=10.xxx.xx.xx,10.yyy.yy.yy --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId' --output text >> InstanceId.txt